# Not able to call class in NHP framework

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-options

I have downloaded fresh framework and installed on my local server. I copied options folder and `nhp-options.php` inside my theme directory. Then I called the class globally by

```
global $NHP_Options;
```

When I try to call copyright information in the footer

```
get("copyright_footer");
```

I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\word\wp-content\themes\mCube\footer.php on line 19

Why is that, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the class method like this:

```
global $NHP_Options;
$copyright = $NHP_Options->get("copyright_footer");
```

if `$NHP_Options` is an instance of the `NHP_Options` class.

Comment: It looks like class not called properly.

Comment: @toscho, thanks for flattening the quotes, I guess they  needed some hammering ;-)  Prashant: do you get any more errors? What is the link to this external library?